# Python: Execute Stored Procedure with Parameters

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on a Python script that writes records from a stored procedure to a text file. I'm having issues executing the stored procedure with parameters.

I'm not sure what I could do differently to execute this stored procedure with both parameters. You can see the error I'm getting below.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Here's my code

```
# Import Python ODBC module
import pyodbc

# Create connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}",server="<server>",database="<database>",uid="<username>",pwd="<password>")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# Execute stored procedure
storedProc = "exec database..stored_procedure('param1', 'param2')"

# Loop through records
for irow in cursor.execute(storedProc):

    # Create a new text file for each ID
    myfile = open('c:/Path/file_' + str(irow[0]) + '_' + irow[1] + '.txt', 'w')

    # Write retrieved records to text file
    myfile.write(irow[2])

    # Close the file
    myfile.close()
```

Here's the error

```
Traceback (most recent call lst):
File "C:\Path\script.py", line 12, in <module>
  for irow in cursor.execute(storedProc):
      pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[4200] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'param1'. <102> <SQLExecDirectW>">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix the syntax error by removing the parenthesis from the query string.

```
# Execute stored procedure
storedProc = "exec database..stored_procedure('param1', 'param2')"
```

should be

```
# Execute stored procedure
storedProc = "exec database..stored_procedure 'param1','param2'"
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
query = "EXEC [store_proc_name] @param1='param1', @param2= 'param2'"
cursor.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server:

```
cursor.execute('{call your_sp (?)}',var_name)
```