# Executing SQL Server stored procedures with parameters in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure to query a table, and am having trouble passing through a parameter successfully.

```
title=cursor.execute("SELECT titlequery(%s)", str(member_id))`
```

`titlequery()` is created by this:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.titlequery(mid text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$

 SELECT title FROM Member WHERE member_id=mid;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql
```

And the error I'm getting:

> modules.pg8000.core.ProgrammingError: ('ERROR', '42P18', 'could not
>   determine data type of parameter $2', 'postgres.c', '1356',
>   'exec_parse_message', '', '')

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: how `member_id` object looks like?

Comment: It is a string, like 'A000042553'

Comment: the query should be `cursor.execute("SELECT titlequery(%s)"%str(member_id))`

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but `execute` expects a sequence (or whatever it's called) as its 2nd parameter. So shouldn't it be `cursor.execute("SELECT titlequery(%s)", (str(member_id),))` or `cursor.execute("SELECT titlequery(%s)", [str(member_id)])`?

Comment: Same issue, even with the brackets.

Comment: To make it clearer:

 `cursor.execute("SELECT first_name_query(%s)", ('A000042553'))`. 

This is producing the same issue still, even though I'm now just inputting the parameter directly instead of using a variable.

Comment: @CallumVanDenHoek: you are missing `,`, `(object)` is the same as `object`, when `(object,)` is a tuple with one element

Comment: follow this to call StoredProcedures:https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/StoredProcedures.wiki

Comment: I have fixed this issue by adding the extra "," , and the function returns the proper information. However, it's returning like so: '[Information]'. Is there something causing the '[]' to appear?

Comment: You can find the answer for this @: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59704648/7303466

Answer (score 1):

[**PEP-249**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) specifies API for database drivers and [`pg8000`](http://pythonhosted.org/pg8000/) follows this API as well

> pg8000 is a DB-API 2.0 compatible pure-Python interface to the PostgreSQL database engine.

From **PEP-249** [`execute` method specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15):

> Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation.

We can see at [`pg8000` sources](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000/blob/4712bd870fec11b10b961a12b54ef7ccb0f70790/pg8000/tests/test_typeconversion.py#L31) an example of how to pass parameters to query.

So you should pass a `tuple`/`list` of values, not value itself.

Also we should execute query first and then fetch its results using [`fetchone`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) or [`fetchmany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchmany) or [`fetchall`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall) because `execute` itself returns [`None`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None) (more at [sources](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000/blob/master/pg8000/core.py#L880-L920)). I guess OP needs one record, so we're going to use `fetchone`.

**Note**: `fetchone` method returns record represented as `tuple`, so if we need first coordinate, then we should [get it using zero index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019909/using-an-index-to-get-an-item-python).

In your case you should try:

```
parameters = (str(member_id),)  # WARNING: don't miss the comma
cursor.execute("SELECT titlequery(%s)", parameters)
title = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

or

```
parameters = [str(member_id)]
cursor.execute("SELECT titlequery(%s)", parameters)
title = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

## Example

This worked for me

```
import pg8000

table_definition = """
    CREATE TABLE Member(
    title VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    member_id VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)
"""
procedure_definition = """
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.titlequery(mid text)
    RETURNS text AS
    $BODY$
     SELECT title FROM Member WHERE member_id=mid;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE sql
"""

connection = pg8000.connect(database='database',
                            user='username',
                            password='password',
                            host='hostname',
                            port=5432)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Preparation
cursor.execute(table_definition)
cursor.execute(procedure_definition)
values = ('Information', 'A000042553')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Member (title, member_id) VALUES (%s, %s)',
               values)

# Reading stored procedure result
parameters = ('A000042553',)
cursor.execute("SELECT titlequery(%s)", parameters)
title = cursor.fetchone()[0]
print(title)

# Cleanup
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

gives us

```
Information
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. I'm now getting the result as '[ result ]'. Where are the ' and [ symbols coming from?

Comment: @CallumVanDenHoek: edited answer, you should execute your query at first and then fetch it with [`fetchone`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) or [`fetchmany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchmany) or [`fetchall`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall)

Comment: @CallumVanDenHoek: completed answer, hope it helps